# Missing Matplotlib Animated Figure in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to create a simple `matplotlib` animation in a Jupyter notebook running inside vscode.

```py
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([])     # A tuple unpacking to unpack the only plot
ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)

def animate(frame_num):
    y = np.sin(x + 2*np.pi * frame_num/100)
    line.set_data((x, y))
    return line

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=5)
plt.show()
```

However, no figure appears after running the cell, just the green tick symbol.

[image]

Using Jupyter extension, both release version `v2022.11.1003412109` and pre-release version `v2023.1.1003441034`.

Is it possible to get the animated matplotlib figure to work inside Vscode Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I usually use jupyterlab, where I `import from Ipython.display import HTML` to animate, I added the following code in vscode and ran your code. The vscode extension is `v2022.11.1003412109`. `#plt.show();from IPython.display import HTML;plt.close();HTML(anim.to_html5_video())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> %matplotlib notebook

As the yellow wavy line says, '%matplotlib' widget works best inside of VS Code.

We use `%matplotlib widget` instead of `%matplotlib notebook,tk,etc`.

VS code should work with these two options (has been thoroughly tested):

- %matplotlib inline - This is the default and will render images as
  PNGs
- %matplotlib widget - This generates an ipywidget that renders plots
  in a control. Multiple plots and zooming are supported. For more
  information see the README

`%matplotlib notebook` is unsupported.

You can use this command with the web version of jupyter notebook.

Read this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Using-%25matplotlib-widget-instead-of-%25matplotlib-notebook,tk,etc/337fc8a9ec47fd56ffb9f2ce29ecf8cbb891d02d) for more information.